# Difference between JMS thread and JMS session worker thread

Tags: multithreading, jboss, jms, message-driven-bean

The thread dump of my application shows "JMSThreads" and "JMS session worker threads".
The # of "JMS Session worker threads" in the thread dump taken at peak time(when a lot of tasks are triggered off) is equal to the maxSessions that I have set in standardJboss.xml .This number is constant across all the dump taken at peak times whereas The # of "JMSthreads" varies in every dump. 
What is the difference between these two?

Comment: It's a platform-specific question, please write what platform you're talking about.

Comment: Its a Struts web application deployed on a JBOSS application server.The application puts in requests in a JMS Queue for asynchrounous processing.

Comment: @MaDa ,is anymore information needed. Please help?

Comment: I've retagged your question to help it reach the proper audience. It's all I can do, I'm afraid, I haven't worked with JBoss.